Continuity of a function on $(0,\infty)$
Given that $f: (0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfies $f(x)=f(\frac{x}{2} +1)$.
If $f$ is continuous at a point $p$, then $f$ is continuous.
I was trying to prove the given statement. I tried using the sequential definition of continuity.
Suppose $x_n \to p$, then $f(x_n)\to f(p)$ and using the given condition we can say $f(\frac{x_n}{2}+1)\to f(\frac{p}{2}+1)=f(p)$. Again using the condition we get  $f(\frac{x_n}{4}+\frac{3}{2})\to f(p)$ and iterating this way, we get countably many sequences that converge to $f(p)$.
If $x_o$ is any arbitrary point of the domain, then $x_n-p+x_o \to x_o$
I am not getting any ideas to proceed with the argument. Any ideas to proceed? Thank you in advance.

It doesn't really seem true.

This is not true. Consider $f(x)=0$ for all $x\neq 2$ and $f(x)=1$ for $x=2$.

You can also make it non-continuous in more violent ways, for example, set $f(x)$ to be $1$ on the irrationals greater than $2$ and $0$ elsewhere.

For any starting point $x_0$, the sequence $(x_{n+1} = x_n/2 + 1)$ converges to $2$, which is also the unique fixed point. The limit is never attained by the sequence unless $x_0 = 2$.
Therefore, the behaviour of $f$ at any point $x_0$ is determined by values of $f$ at some points (dependent on $x_0$!) near $2$. But also, we are free to choose $f(2)$ as we please. So unless $p = 2$, the statement is false, because continuity at $2$ is not necessarily true. And more serious examples may be given, as $(x_{n+1} = x_n/2 + 1)$ does not mix rationals and irrationals, for example.
However, if $f$ is continuous at $p = 2$, then $f$ is continuous everywhere. For by the triangle inequality $$|f(x) - f(x_0)| \leq |f(x) - f(2)| + |f(x_0) - f(2)|$$
for any $x_0$ and $x$ near $x_0$. By iteration, the values $f(x_0)$ and $f(x)$ are both also values of $f$ in any small neighbourhood around $2$.
Follow-up question for OP: what if $f$ is only right-continuous/left-continuous at $2$?

HINT.-$f(x)=\text{constant}$ is a possibility. But otherwise this property is exclusive of linear functions and $f$ is not linear.
